# Access viewmodel in knockout mapping plugin

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am using the knockout mapping plugin to add a computed property to an item in a observable array. However, this computed property relies on a different property in my viewmodel.

How do I access a viewmodel property when creating an observable during mapping?

Please note that I cannot use options.parent, because the property is further up in the viewModel.

I also am unable to change the viewmodel, because it is generated server side.

Edit:

Here's a JSFiddle that shows the issue. The line that is commented out is what I need to get working.

http://jsfiddle.net/g46mt/2/

This is what I have now, but it is obviously throwing an error:

```
var mapping = {
    'Collection': {
        create: function(options) {
            var model = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
            model.Total = ko.computed(function() {
                var result = this.Price() * viewModel.Count(); // :(
                return result;
            }, model);

            return model;
        }
    }
};

var json = { ... large json object ... };
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(json, mapping);
```

Comment: Please post at least the relevant parts of your json structure! We need at least the location of the `Collection` and the `Price` and the `Count` property and also where do you want to have the `Total` proeprty.

Comment: I didn't think the json was relevant, since the question is not about a specific json structure. But I've added a working JSFiddle that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use the `{deferEvaluation: true}` option. So your computed function will be only evaluated when the `viewModel` is ready and your `Total` property is actually used:

```
var mapping = {
    'Collection': {
        create: function(options) {
            var model = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
            model.Total = ko.computed(function() {
                var result = this.Price() * viewModel.Count();
                return result;
            }, model, {deferEvaluation: true});
            return model;
        }
    }
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2RCF/).

However with this approach you are tightly coupling your view model name with your mapping options. Because if you ever change `var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(json, mapping);` and name your `viewModel` differently then you have to also update the mapping configuration.

Because there is no way to walk the "parent" chain in the mapping config probably for this scenario the mapping plugin is not the best solution...

Here is an alternative approach using handwritten viewmodels and passing down the "root" where is it needed:

```
var MainViewModel = function (json) {    
    ko.mapping.fromJS(json, { 'ignore': ["Foo"] }, this); //map the rest
    this.Foo = new FooViewModel(json.Foo, this);
}

var FooViewModel = function (json, root) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(json, { 'ignore': ["Bar"] }, this); //map the rest
    this.Bar = new BarViewModel(json.Bar, root);
}

var BarViewModel = function (json, root) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(json, { 'ignore': ["Collection"] }, this); //map the rest
    this.Collection = ko.mapping.fromJS(json.Collection, {
       create: function(options) {
            var model = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
            model.Total = ko.computed(function() {
                var result = this.Price() * root.Count();
                return result;
            }, model);

            return model;

       }});
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kE8pC/1/).

Answer (score 1):

With the mapping plugin, it is possible to map from multiple sources. I think you could just do

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(json);
viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(json, mapping, viewModel),
```

After the first time mapping, you have your Collection with each Price as an observable. After the 2nd mapping, you'd have Total as well as an observable.

[demo i jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g46mt/4/)

Comment: Yeah, but this solution walks though the whole `json` structure twice, and it also does not solve the problem of having the `viewModel` variable name in the mapping configuration...

Comment: @nemesv I'm aware of the that it walks the structure twice, and I do like the second solution you came up with, which prevents this. The `viewModel` variable name is in my opinion not an issue that one need to worry about. What if if the Count variable in the json structure changes name? That to me is an equeal dependency in the mapping configuration.

Comment: The `Count` and in fact the `Price` are different dependencies. They need to changed only when the JSON structure changes and there is no way to avoid this. If a contract/interface changes both end needs to changed... However the `viewModel` is a different dependency on the name of the variable which can be changed independently and even without realizing that there is a dependency. It is very dangerous that with a simple refactoring (rename local variable) you can break your code in a totally unrelated place.